# Prove whether or not a subgroup is normal in the dihedral group $D_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

> Let $H$ be the subgroup of the dihedral group $D_4$ generated by the elements $\left<I\ (\text{identity}),p^2\epsilon\ (\text{flip across the horizontal diagonal})\right>$. I have to tell whether or not this is a normal subgroup of the dihedral group $D_4$ (the regular polygon with 4 sides).

I know that $H = \{I,p^2\epsilon\}$. After that I made the multyplicative tale of D_4 and I saw that that $xH = Hx, \forall x \in D_4$, therefor H is normal in $D_4$. But I'm not sure if this is the way it should be done. I think that there is another way which does not imply the multyplicative table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a subgroup of order $2$ is normal if and only if its non-identity element is in the center. So you just need to find a permutation that does not commute with the horizontal flip. For example, rotating by $90$ degrees clockwise. So the subgroup is not normal.

Comment: To check it works try it out with a book :) (flipping and then rotating and in the other order)

Comment: And if you don't like flipping books, note that $r^2$, which is rotation by 180 degrees, commutes with all rotations and also with your flip $f$, since $fr^{2} = r^{-2}f = r^2 f$, so $r^2$ commutes with all elements. Therefore the center $Z$ contains $r^2$. As the order of $Z$ can't be $8$ (since $D_4$ is not abelian) and can't be $4$ (since that would mean $D_4 / Z$ would have order $2$, hence would be cyclic, hence $D_4$ would be abelian), this means that $Z$ contains only $\{1, r^2\}$ and hence does not contain your subgroup.