# The dihedral group $D_8$ isn't Hamiltonian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

Let $D_8=\{a^ib^j:i\in\{0,1\},j\in\{0,...,3\}\} $ be a dihedral group, where
$$a=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad b=\begin{pmatrix}
cos\theta  & -sin\theta \\ 
sin\theta & cos\theta
\end{pmatrix},$$
with $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{4}$. Prove that $D_8$ is **not** a Hamiltonian group.

Comment: I think you have some spelling mistakes.  Please review and edit.

Comment: What is a Hemiltonic (or hemiltonic) group?

Comment: Hamiltonian subgroup, i.e., non-abelian group all of whose subgroups  are normal. For the dihedral group with $8$ elements this is not the case, as we know, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889610/prove-whether-or-not-a-subgroup-is-normal-in-the-dihedral-group-d-4?rq=1), or [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Non-normal_subgroups_of_dihedral_group:D8).

Answer (score 0):

To show that $D_8$ is not Hamiltonian, it suffices to find a subgroup that is *not* normal. Since $D_8$ has only $8$ elements, it isn't a lot of work to check all cyclic subgroups, i.e. to check $\langle x\rangle$ for all $x\in D_8$.